# Can Rust macros deal with multiple-layer nested expressions?

Tags: macros, rust

The following code is a simple test of `macro_rule!`'s limit. It correctly prints `[1, 2]` as the target.

```
macro_rules! test {
    ($target:tt) => {
        println!("{:?}", $target);
    };
    ($target:tt, $($rest:tt),*) => {
        test!($target)
    };
    ([$target:tt, $($inner_rest:tt),*],$($rest:tt),*) => {
        test!($target)
    }
}

fn main() {
    test![[1, 2], [[5, 6], 3], 4];
}
```

However, if I change `[[1,2]` to `[[1,2],3]`, the compiler complains:

```
<anon>:16:15: 16:16 error: mismatched types:
 expected `[_; 2]`,
    found `_`
(expected array of 2 elements,
    found integral variable) [E0308]
<anon>:16  test![[[1,2],3],[[5,6],3],4];
                        ^
<std macros>:2:25: 2:56 note: in this expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: in this expansion of print! (defined in <std macros>)
<anon>:4:5: 4:30 note: in this expansion of println! (defined in <std macros>)
<anon>:7:6: 7:20 note: in this expansion of test! (defined in <anon>)
<anon>:16:2: 16:31 note: in this expansion of test! (defined in <anon>)
<anon>:16:15: 16:16 help: see the detailed explanation for E0308
error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

Is there a way to let the macro recursively deal with brackets and print the first item? I have studied [the example given by the Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/macros.html), but still have no idea about how to implement it in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked it to parse an expression, so that's exactly what it *tried* to do.

The first thing it sees is `[[1, 2], 3]` which is invalid because it's an array literal where the first element is of type `[i32; 2]` and the second element is of type `i32`.  So, it fails.

If you want to macro to deal with recursive syntax, you're going to have to write it to handle it.  I have no idea what you're trying to do ("deal with bracket" *how?*), so I can't offer a concrete example.  Try adding an extra rule *before* the existing ones that explicitly deals with `[[$($stuff:tt)*] ...`.  Rules are processed top-to-bottom, so you need to put the most specific rule first. The following prints out `[1, 2]`:

```rust
macro_rules! test {
    ([$target:tt, $($inner_rest:tt),*], $($rest:tt),*) => {
        test!($target)
    };
    ($target:tt) => {
        println!("{:?}", $target);
    };
    ($target:tt, $($rest:tt),*) => {
        test!($target)
    };
}

fn main() {
    test![[[1,2],3],[[5,6],3],4];
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I have updated the question with a recursive macro,  but it still does not work. Could you please point out what is wrong?

Comment: @divinites You still haven't indicated *what* you want the macro to do?  I've taken a guess at what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want.